# How to replace incomplete files with originals using bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have 2 directories with both many unidentical subdirectories.

One has 'half' extracted `.mkv` files in it imported by another program.

The seconds has the original completely extracted `.mkv` files in it.

---

I'm trying to write a bash script to replace the corrupted .mkv files with the original files.
The filenames in both directories are the same but the subdirectories and filesizes differ.

---

I've tried to write or alter many solutions involving `find`, `fdupes` and `grep`.

But I just can't get it to work. Can somebody help me?

---

Incomplete example

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname1=/mnt/raid1/dir1
dirname2=/mnt/raid1/dir2
find $dirname1 -name '*.mkv'
while read fileName
do
find $dirname2 -type f | grep "$fileName"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If the file names are the same just using `mv` should do the trick:

```bsh
# traverse the original's directory
for o in original/*/*.mkv; do
  # traverse the corrupted's directory
  for c in corrupted/*/*.mkv; do 
    # if a corrupted file has the same name as an original's
    # perform the `mv` command replacing the former
    if [[ "$(basename "$o")" = "$(basename "$c")" ]]; then
      mv -- "$o" "$c"; 
    fi
  done
done
```

[The double dash `--` means](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02):

> Guideline 10:
> The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the '-' character.

You can use the option `-i` which will prompt a question before overwriting a file... which can be cumbersome if you have thousands of files.

```bsh
mv -i -- "$o" "$c"
mv: overwrite 'corrupted/<sub dir>/filename.mkv'?
```

Note: *in general*, it's better to do a backup of the data before performing this kind of overwriting/deleting operations.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The files are in different unknown subdirectories though.
I should have mentioned that the path in both directories should be searched.
So for instance /dir1/xxxxxxxxx//file.mkv and /dir2/yyyyyyyyy/file.mkv.
There are about 4000 files in separate directories, some are complete some aren't.

Comment: @RémonvanNieuwenhuizen good day, it's 5am here in Argentina, I'm a little drowsy, so for now this is the best I can do =D... I don't like nested loops but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat || exit

orig_dir=/mnt/raid1/dir1
incomplete_dir=/mnt/raid1/dir2

typeset -A where size

for f in $orig_dir/**/*.mkv(ND.); do
  stat -A s +size -- $f || continue
  if (( $+where[$f:t] )); then
    print -ru2 -- "$f:t is found in more than one place ($where[$f:t] and $f at least)!"
    exit 1
  fi
  where[$f:t]=$f size[$f:t]=$s
done

# for dry-run (comment out when happy)
cp() (PS4='Would run'; set -x; : cp "$@")

ret=0
for f in $incomplete_dir/**/*.mkv(ND.); do
  stat -A s +size -- $f || continue
  if (( $size[$f:t] > $s )); then
    cp -- $where[$f:t] $f || ret=$?
  fi
done
exit $ret
```

(untested).

To only add the missing part of the files instead of copying files whole, you can do:

```
zmodload zsh/system
resume() {
  {
    sysseek -w end -u 1 0 &&
      sysseek -w start -u 0 $(( systell(1) )) &&
      cat
  } < $1 1<> $2
}
```

And use `resume` in place of `cp --` above.